# Replace string resources content when gradle builds

Tags: android, xml, string, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an app with 2 flavors. Each flavor support a lot of languages.
I have strings containing the flavor's name. For example:

```
<string name="test_string">Flavor 1 is an app to do something</string>
```

I could do:

```
<string name="test_string_flavor1">Flavor 1 is an app to do something</string>
<string name="test_string_flavor2">Flavor 2 is an app to do something</string>
```

(All the strings for the same language need to be in the same *strings* file as the tool I'm using to manage the translation can't deal with flavors.)

Then I can create 2 separated strings files, one for each flavor:

**File for flavor 1**

```
<string name="test_string">@string/test_string_flavor1</string>
```

**File for flavor 2**

```
<string name="test_string">@string/test_string_flavor2</string>
```

And then use *test_string* inside the app.

But I can't do that as it's gonna be a nightmare to manage the translation (only the flavor's name change, the rest of the string needs to be identical) and it's too difficult to maintain.

So I'm looking or another solution.
I'm thinking that maybe I could replace the flavor's name in the string resource when gradle builds them but:

1. I'm not sure it's possible.
2. There is maybe an easier option.

Comment: why this way though?

Comment: 'Cause I don't see any other solution.